# Dynamically adding and removing objects in response to selectInput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building a shiny app to visualise a large geographic dataset. I want the user to be able to select a region from a drop down menu and then checkboxes will appear below the drop down menu with the names of the smaller geographic regions within the first region. The user will then be able to click on each check box and the region will be highlighted on a map and they will be provided with data describing that region.

It almost works except for the fact that once a user has selected one region from the drop down menu and the checkboxes have appeared beneath it, if they then change their selection in the drop down menu the checkboxes for their first selection are not removed. Instead the second set of checkboxes appears above it.

Here are the relevant sections of my code:

**UI.R**

```
    ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = 'region', choices = c('All', admin1_regions_list), label = 'Select an admin1 region:'), #creates drop down menu, first argument is the id
    verbatimTextOutput('empty_box'), #creates empty box so that checkboxes will sit after it
  )
)
```

**SERVER.R**

```
server <- function(input, output){

observe({ # listens for input

    x <- input$region #input from drop down menu which has the id 'region'

      removeUI(selector = "div:has(> #admin2_checkboxes)", immediate = TRUE)      

      insertUI(
        selector = '#empty_box', #empty box is used as placeholder, sits just below first drop down menu in ui
        where = 'afterEnd', #where in relation to empty box should the checkbox input be
        ui = checkboxGroupInput(inputId = 'admin2_checkboxes', label = 'Select an admin2 region:',
                            choices = admin2_list)
          )
})
})
```

I thought that the `removeUI()` function call immediately before inserting the new one would do what I wanted but it doesn't appear to be doing anything. Is this because the selector isn't correct? (I also set it to `"div:has(> #empty_box)"`, i.e. the same selector as the `inputUI()` function call but that didn't work either). Or do I need to restructure my code?

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't run your code and I haven't used your approach before to solve this problem. However, the following example has a dynamically updating group checkbox based on the car make selected. Is that the functionality you were after (if not the approach).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('make', choices = c("-", "Merc", "Cadillac", "Fiat"), label = 'Select a car make:'), #creates drop down menu, first argument is the id
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.make != '-'",
                     uiOutput("select_car"))
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$select_car <- renderUI({
    
    choices <- rownames(mtcars)[grep(input$make, rownames(mtcars))]
    
    checkboxGroupInput('cars', label = 'Select cars:',
                       choices = choices)
  })
  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: No problem - glad to help!